# How to get Laravel 5.2 model field names and types for generic forms

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to build a generic form creator which basically takes a certain Eloquent model and automatically builds a form with all its fields.

Therefor I would need to know the all fields and their (data-)types of the model. So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to do this and is it a smart idea in general?
2. Is there any easy-to-use package, that does the same thing and works with laravel 5.2. (I tried [FrozenNode's *Laravel-Administrator*](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator) but the dos is only for laravel 4 and I don't need all its functionality)

Thanks for your help!

Best,
Simon

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I am doing this:

```
$model = new ExampleModel();
$model->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($model->getTable());
```

to you model add method :

```
public function getColumnsNames() {
    return (array) $this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($this->getTable());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$schema = \DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager();
$columns = $schema->listTableColumns('table_name'); //get table columns
foreach ($table->getColumns() as $column) { //run loop
   $column->getName(). - .$column->getType()->getName(); //here you can define your inputes
}
```

Comment: I get a Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found Exception and actually PHP Strom can not find \DB Namespace. The functions are also no available on the DB:: Facade. I found your Code only in relation with Laravel 4, might this have changed in Laravel 5 (5.2)? @Froxz

Comment: @Simon cant't be I use DB in laravel 5.1 `'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,` This should be in your config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the various solutions I found is that they all rely on Doctrine which is no longer included as part of Laravel.

This is why you are getting that Doctrine\DBAL error.

So, I tried including it as a dependency but that still gave the error.

While I was looking through the source code, trying to solve the error, I noticed that there was another method: getPdo().

So, in desperation, I used that.

```
$pdo = \DB::getPdo();
$select = $pdo->query('SELECT '.$field.' FROM '.$table. ' WHERE ID = "'.$id.'"');
$meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);
dd($meta);
```

In this instance, this returned:

```
array:7 [
"native_type" => "VAR_STRING"
"pdo_type" => 2
"flags" => array:1
"table" => "photologs"
"name" => "slug"
"len" => 60
"precision" => 0
]
```

Now, this is messy, and you have to run another query to get your results.

In my instance, I was developing a method that would give you all the information on a specific field, so already knew the table and field name.

My solution is by no means complete, however it does actually work, and you should be able to adapt it to suit.

If you found a better way though, do tell!